# mysqldump backup and restore to remote server

Tags: mysql

How can i use mysqldump to backup and restore database to a remote server?

Both have root access. I am using putty to perform this.

So far I tried the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -p >z*x311a!@ masdagn_joom15 | mysql \ -u root -p g2154hE6-AsXP --host=207.210.71.26 -C masdagn_joom15temp \g
```

but it refused

the local password is: >z*x311a!@

the remote password is: g2154hE6-AsXP

Comment: For future notice, I'd be cautious about publicly posting your database credentials.  Hope you've changed them!

Comment: if you can only see a blank shell input field after using the command it probably means that mysqldump is still working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) provides information on backing up and restoring with mysqldump. It also gives some examples with a remote server.

The important commands from that link being:

**backup:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

**restore:**

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: i am really using this

but when i enter the command mysqldump

it gives me nothing

only the command prompt again

Answer (score 4):

```
[local-server]# mysqldump -u root -prootpswd db | mysql \
                 -u root -ptmppassword --host=remote-server -C db1
```

[Note: There are two -- (hyphen) in front of host]

Please note that you should first create the db1 database on the remote-server before executing the following command.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=pwd db_name | bzip2 -c > /backup_dir/db_name.sql.bz2
```

you can embed this part in a script, afterward you can use FTP to transfer to the other location.

To restore, you can

```
bzip2 -d db_name.sql.bz2
mysql --user=username --password=pwd db_name < db_name.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Your local password contains the `>` character, which is interpreted as a [redirect character](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) by most shells. As a general rule, it will make your life considerably easier if you keep your MySQL passwords alphanumeric `[A-Za-z0-9]`. And it will make your system more secure if you avoid publicly posting your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I do for a quick dump to another remote server...
assuming that you have setup an ssh key between the 2 servers

- create file dump-to-server.sh
- chmod to executable (`chmod 0755 dump-to-server.sh`)
- run your sync `./dump-to-server.sh schema_name root@remote.server.net`

***dump-to-server.sh***

```
\#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" || -z "$2" ]]; then
  echo "--------- usage ---------";
  echo "./dump-to-server.sh schema_name root@remote.server.net";
  echo "";
else
  mysqldump --opt "$1" | gzip -c | ssh "$2" "gunzip -c | mysql $1"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single DB, Taking backup from a remote server is :

`mysqldump -u<user> -p<pwd> -h<remote-host> [database-name] > dump.sql`

Restore is:

`mysql -u<user> -p<pwd> -h<remote-host> [database-name] < dump.sql`

more details about options of mysqldump are available here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html